# Equivariant resolution of singularities in positive characteristic

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

The base field $k$ is assumed to be algebraically closed of positive characteristic.

It is now classical that for $3$-dimensional varieties (over $k$) there always exists a resolution of singularities. Let $G$ be an affine algebraic group (not necessarily finite), and let $X$ be a singular $G$-variety of dimension $3$.

> **Question.** Does there always exist a $G$-equivariant resolution of singularities for $X$?

I am aware that if the base field $k$ were of characteristic zero, then the answer would be positive by a result of Kollar (Prop 3.9.1 in Kollar's book *Lectures on resolution of singularities*).